# trigger.io customise native button toolbar and tabbar

Tags: ios, user-interface, trigger.io

Is it possible to customise the topbar and tabbar button backgrounds in trigger.io?

Specifically, I'd like to be able to specify the 'active' state background, rather than the default.

However, I suspect this isn't within the scope of what trigger.io is aiming to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, no - those backgrounds aren't configurable.

If it's urgent for you, this could be achieved with a [native plugin](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/native/). If that's not an option for you, this is the sort of thing we could and would add to the tabbar and topbar modules ourselves: get in touch at support@trigger.io to discuss timescales.

Comment: Thanks James. I'll look into the plugin route.
 - Additionally

Comment: Oops, didn't finish...
Additionally, Can you recommend a place look to begin? I'm not an ios expert :-)

Comment: I'm doing the first in a series of webinars on plugin development next week (14th March 2013). That's a good place for an introduction. Or, jump into the docs! http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/native/